# Basic doubts about dynamics of a rod

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

[image]
[image]
I have few doubts in the given solution.

1. It says there is no force along the plane but $mgcos\alpha$ is acting along the plane ?
2. As given, $A$ is used as orgin. Then how come x-co-ordinate of $G$ is 
   $acos\alpha$ because i think the rod is translating as well ?
3. I didn't get how they got the expression for translation kinetic energy.

Comment: what? As far as I can tell, $\ddot \phi = -\frac{3g}a\cos(\alpha-\phi)$.

Comment: I get this results

$\ddot{\varphi}=-\frac{g}{a}\,\cos(\varphi+\alpha)$ and

$R=-\sin(\varphi)\left(\sin(\varphi-\alpha)\,m\,g+a\,\dot{\varphi}^2\right)$

Comment: I think that equation (2) is dimensionally incorrect.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: @Kyle sure.  
@ Farcher - there is a misprint in that line